# Ambiguous tag: f5

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, ambiguous-tags

The tag [f5](/questions/tagged/f5) is used for referring to both f5 load balancers and browser refreshing action by pressing the function <kbd>F5</kbd> key. As of now there are only 28 questions with the [f5](/questions/tagged/f5) tag.

I guess this won't be straightforward change as the majority of users would associate f5 to the keyboard key naturally than the load balancer (especially on stackoverflow, but may differ on serverfault). Should we create a tag named [f5-networks](/questions/tagged/f5-networks) for question relating to the load balancers and related hardware?

Comment: I can't imagine what will happen to the Total Commander users who are having problems using the F5 key to copy files

Comment: If anything, [tag:f5-networks] would be sufficient, but I think [tag:f5] is just fine. [tag:f5-networks-inc] is overkill, it's not [tag:microsoft-corp], but [tag:microsoft], after all.

Comment: @JoachimSauer good point. changing my recommendation in the question accordingly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't see the point in having <kbd>F5</kbd> as a representation of the F5 key. What those users are *meaning* to express is the process of *reloading a page*.

I'm in favour of letting `f5` be the tag for the load balancer product, and re-tagging all key related questions to `page-reload` or something (if the tag makes sense at all. In my opinion, it could just be removed.)

Comment: I'll fix the "keyboard F5" questions unless any major vetoes come up

Comment: An update to the tag wiki to clarify this, as well as the fact it's *not* to be used for the F5 key would be ideal.

Comment: @casper I created a Wiki but on closer look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F5_Networks, it seems like F5 is the name of the company, and their flagship product is BIG-IP. You can see from some of the tags that what the users tried to add was `F5 BIG IP`. I'm wondering whether we should create `f5-big-ip` instead and retag them all to that? Not sure whether "F5" is used as a synonym for the flagship product, maybe somebody with domain knowledge could clarify?

Comment: @Pekka웃: You are correct, but at work and when communicating with other we simply refer to the product as F5. So, I guess the word F5 simply means either their big-ip LB or the SSL offloader or the firewall depending on the context.

Answer (score 3):

I personally can't see any need for an entire tag corresponding to using the <kbd>F5</kbd> key, but that does seem to be the primary usage for it (I'd argue this is simply bad tagging practices). 28 questions isn't exactly a daunting amount to go through and tag appropriately, so the existing [f5](/questions/tagged/f5) tag could simply be re-purposed to refer specifically to the load balancers.

The tag wiki will need to be updated to make its intended usage clear, regardless of what we decide it should be used for.